# Windows Phone 7 - Maps Streetside

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

Is it possible to use the Streetside libraries on the Windows Phone?

I've downloaded and installed both the Maps Controls for Silverlight and the Extended Modes and I am able to run them inside Silverlight but I can't seem to get the Extended Mode Streetside to work on the phone.

Streetside Library for Silverlight Tutorial: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2009/12/10/adding-streetside-and-enhanced-birds-eye-to-your-applications.aspx

Extended Modes Library:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SilverlightMapModesBeta

Comment: Is anything from the extended modes dlls working on wp7?

Comment: I haven't tried with anything else. For the moment I've moved on from that to try other alternatives. I would still love to use it if it's possible to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extended modes library is does not currently support wp7.